# How to organize Angular modal component with different uses?

Tags: angular

I'm working in Angular 7, and I have an upcoming feature where a user can choose to create, edit, merge, or split user groups. When the user selects any of these options, a modal pops up with the form they need for that action. The UI design has the modals for all of these with the same general look, but the form options and form layout are quite different between all four (one has two columns, another has one column with a table at the bottom, for example). I was wondering what were some good ways to organize my components for this modal.

My ideas so far:

1. Base modal component, and use child components for importing the actual modal content
2. One component that has all four modal templates, and the appropriate modal template is called by the parent component (the main page, which has the menu for selecting the create, edit, merge, and split actions)

Comment: I'm not sure my own approach would be the "best", but I would go with option 1. Create a base modal in a shared module, then the modal content components would be defined wherever they fit best. If each content component is shared across the application, they would also be in the shared module. If they're specific to a given feature / module, I'd keep them in that module.

Comment: option 1 is usually the way this will go as it scales far better. but why reinvent the wheel here when angular material already provides modal / dialog functionality

Comment: Hi Catherine, I am voting to close the questions because it is pretty opinion based. I would start building and do not over think it too much, you can refactor and you will refactor as you go to better organize. You can have a modal component that loads body content abstractly but it will be hard to access your model bindings on changes in parent components possibly so keep that in mind and do not make things harder than they need to be at the start. I would also add another point, you may very well but, part of your requirements is just as much about CSS organization/classes.